# Is the Python GIL shared by threads in a process or is it shared by all threads in all processes?

Tags: python, gil

Do we have 1 GIL per processor 1 GIL on the entire computer (shared by all processes)?

When we say shared variables need to be locked when modifying values, then do we mean the variables declared in the target thread function or those variables that are declared outside the thread function and modified in the thread function?

Comment: 1 GIL per process. Processes are separate to _threads_, which you go on to mention.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any comment on the shared variables (lock)? Or should I create separate question for it?

Comment: @variable hello, did the answer help to solve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each process have it's own memory, threads of one process have access to memory of the parent Process. So one GIL per process. GIL exists to prevent different threads from changing the same part of memory simultaneously.

Lock is a primitive in threading module which allows only one thread to have access to some varilable in the current moment, it is used for different Counters, or e.g. we want threads to write to file one after another, rather all together (Note that GIL does not affect IN/OUT operations, hereby it is possible to write to file all together).

Threading Lock example:

```
import threading
import logging


def worker_with(lock):
    with lock:  # block, then release
        logging.debug('Lock acquired via with')


def worker_no_with(lock):
    lock.acquire()  # block
    try: 
        logging.debug('Lock acquired directly')
    finally:
        lock.release()  # release


logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format='(%(threadName)-10s) %(message)s',)
lock = threading.Lock()  # Lock instance

w = threading.Thread(target=worker_with, args=(lock,))
nw = threading.Thread(target=worker_no_with, args=(lock,))

w.start()
nw.start()
```

Comment: What you mean by it is possible to write to file all together

Comment: @variable all together = threads compete for access to file stream and as a result you get mesh of outputs from different threads, to prevent it use Lock